# calling an overridden method from base class?

Tags: python

[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/userdict.html) -

> Guido, the original author of Python, explains method overriding this way: "Derived classes may override methods of their base classes. Because methods have no special privileges when calling other methods of the same object, a method of a base class that calls another method defined in the same base class, may in fact end up calling a method of a derived class that overrides it. (For C++ programmers: all methods in Python are effectively virtual.)" If that doesn't make sense to you (it confuses the hell out of me), feel free to ignore it. I just thought I'd pass it along.

I am trying to figure out an example for: *a method of a base class that calls another method defined in the same base class, may in fact end up calling a method of a derived class that overrides it*

```
class A:      
  def foo(self): print 'A.foo'      
  def bar(self): self.foo()                  

class B(A):      
  def foo(self): print 'B.foo'     

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  a = A()                
  a.bar()                   # echoes A.foo
  b = B()
  b.bar()                   # echoes B.foo
```

... but both of these seem kind of obvious.

am I missing something that was hinted out in the quote?

---

### UPDATE

edited typo of calling `a.foo()` (instead of `a.bar()`)and `b.foo()` (instead of `b.bar()`) in the original code

Comment: dirty hack to get at parent `b.__class__.__mro__[1].hi(A())`

Comment: @Jakob: why not `super`?

Comment: @Eli Returns NULL on python2.6.6 ? :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you're missing this:

```
b.bar()   # echoes B.foo
```

`B` has no `bar` method of its own, just the one inherited from `A`. `A`'s `bar` calls `self.foo`, but in an instance of `B` ends up calling `B`'s `foo`, and not `A`'s `foo`.

Let's look at your quote again:

> a method of a base class that calls
>   another method defined in the same
>   base class, may in fact end up calling
>   a method of a derived class that
>   overrides it

To translate:

> `bar` (method of `A`, the base class)
>   calls `self.foo`, but may in fact end up
>   calling a method of the derived class
>   that overrides it (`B.foo` that
>   overrides `A.foo`)

Comment: oops! I made a blunder, I meant `b.bar()` both times in the original code: (and it still seemed obvious, since B inherits A, it has `bar()` too but I just cannot see it. Moreover since I am explicitly passing `self` it is clear it's B' object)

Comment: @Vaibhav: if this seems obvious, then good - what else? In C++, by the way, unless the methods are virtual it won't work this way. So it's not globally obvious. In Python, thinking in C++'s terms, all methods are virtual

Comment: should I change my code to reflect the original question? (but I don't want to be rude since your answer corresponds to this one)

Comment: @Vaibhav: I guess you can change it, just note it explicitly with "Update". The important thing is that I hope you no longer are confused

Answer (score 9):

Note, this won't work for private methods in Python 3.6:

```
class A:      
  def __foo(self): print 'A.foo'      
  def bar(self): self.__foo()                  

class B(A):      
  def __foo(self): print 'B.foo'     

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  a = A()                
  a.bar()                   # echoes A.foo
  b = B()
  b.bar()                   # echoes A.foo, not B.foo
```

I spent an hour to find out the reason for this

Comment: Thanks to your comment I spent just 10 minutes while searching for the same!

Comment: This is actually the *only purpose* for double-underscore name-mangling.

Comment: what *is* the reason for this?

Comment: @IlyaP only 10 minutes? I think I've just spent an hour on it. Thanks Mr. Pavel! Stupid private Python methods that are not really private but also do not work as virtual protected method grumble mumble grumble I want my hour back!!!