# Why is my superclass calling my subclass method?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, subclass, superclass

When I call a method that was overrided from my constructor, I am getting an error and it says that it is missing an argument (due to the subclass requiring a second argument). However, I called the method in the super(), so why doesn't it call the super class version of that method?

This is best illustrated with a short example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        print("A")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.do("B")

    def do(self, arg2):
        super().do()
        print(arg2)


b = B()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Python/Advanced/randomStuff/supersub.py", line 19, in <module>
        b = B()
    File "D:/Python/Advanced/randomStuff/supersub.py", line 11, in __init__
        super().__init__()
    File "D:/Python/Advanced/randomStuff/supersub.py", line 3, in __init__
        self.do()
TypeError: do() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

It seems to be calling the do() method in class B, but I want to call the do() method in Class A.
Ideally, the code should print:

```
A
A
B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that a base class that calls a method that is defined on itself, but also overridden by a subclass, calls the *overridden method on the subclass* not the method on the base class. For further information see [calling an overridden method from base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620832/calling-an-overridden-method-from-base-class). See the below variant of your code and follow the logic as described above.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        print("do A")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        super().do()
        print("do B")


b = B()
```

Result:
A
B
A
B

Answer (score 2):

This effect was a surprise to me, too - thanks for pointing it out.  Geeks for Geeks [provides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-parent-class-method/) a simple way to force the superclass constructor to use an overridden method of the superclass by substituting `A.do(self)` for `self.do()` in the superclass constructor:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        A.do(self)

    def do(self):
        print("A")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        super().do()
        print("B")


b = B()
```

This will produce

```
A
A
B
```

as required.

Answer (score 0):

This is really curious. I don't have a solution but the below appears to work as intended. It is exactly the same except for super() is called explicitly with self.**class** as an argument, which I thought was implicit.

Maybe a more skilled Pythonista can build on this observation.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__).__init__()
        self.do("B")

    def do(self, arg2):
        super().do()
        print(arg2)

print('***init A***')
a = A()
print('***init B***')
b = B()
print('***A.do()***')
a.do()
print('***B.do()***')
b.do('test')
```