# Why in Python the parent's init calls child's overridden method?

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes. The *Child* has a different signature (number of arguments).  Take a look at this MRE (minimal reproducible example):

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.some_method(arg)  # it was intended to call the Parent's some_method
    
    def some_method(self, arg1):  # why this method is not called from Parent's __init__?
        print(f"Parent method called with arg1: {arg1}")


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self, "Hello")
        # the child __init__ does not need to call some_method
    
    def some_method(self, arg1, arg2):  # child has two arguments. Why Child's some_method called from Parent's __init__?
        print(f"Child method called with arg1: {arg1} and arg2: {arg2}")
        super().some_method(arg1)


child = Child()  # getting an exception
```

Expected result:

```
Parent method called with arg1: Hello
```

Actual result:

```
TypeError: Child.some_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

As can be seen, it was called **Child**.some_method().

Why this is happening? Is it possible to keep different number of arguments and keep this working?

---

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51514472/7869636), but its intention was opposite to mine - he *wanted* that parent called the child method.

Comment: Also related (and linked in the above question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620832/calling-an-overridden-method-from-base-class

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because inside the *Parent* class in init, the *self* is pointing to *Child* object, not to *Parent* object.

To solve the problem, the *Parent* class should explicitly call its own *some_method*:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        Parent.some_method(self, arg)  # always will call Parent's some_method()
```

Comment: yes it's doing that because the name "some_method" is re-assigned to the default, which is in Child when inheriting the Parent class.

Comment: The `self` argument (which you omitted) will have the same issue within `Parent.some_method` and more things may break in the same way.

Comment: @Woodword While there are some remarks to be made about this answer, including the `self` explicitly in the call like it is now won't have the same issue: this will call the method as defined in the `Parent` class. 
Of course, what is needed here is someone to guide the O.P. on how Object Oriented programming and inheritance is meant to work, and any answer not doing that is just playing around.